# EXCEL VBA Transposing data: Run Time Error 1004 Paste Special Method of Range Class Failed

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code online to transpose my data that was downloaded into the first column. Every time I run this code, I get a "Run-time error '1004'" Paste Special Method of Range class failed. I can't seem to figure out what the issue was. I properly highlighted all the data and ensured the transposed cells were empty.

```
    Sub Transpose_N_Rows()

    xRow = Selection.Rows.Count
    xCol = Selection.Column

    nextRow = 1

    stepValue = InputBox("How many rows should be grouped together?")


    For i = 1 To xRow Step stepValue


        Cells(i, xCol).Resize(stepValue).Copy


        Cells(1, xCol).Offset(nextRow, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True

        nextRow = nextRow + 1

    Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any merged cells? Is the worksheet protected?

Comment: I don't have any merged cells